# Query execution slow

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.5

I am using `postgresql` db,
When I execute this following Query in `postgresql` it is running very Slow.

```
select * from <table_name>;
```

Previously it takes `5ms` but now it takes around `15 mins` still it is running.
Can anyone suggest what are the possible reason?

Comment: First read here [Explain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html)  Share your execution plan..

Comment: Yes, but make that `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`.